# Rails routes, url and subdomain

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes, subdomain

We are using some subdomain in our app.

All our dashboards have a subdomain(pro.domain.com, free.domain.com, vip.domain.com).
In the route, each dashboard has a namespace `namespace :vip do`

With rails url I'd like to be able to write `<%= link_to "Be VIP", vip_pricing_path() %>` and be redirected to vip.domain.com/pricing

I don't really know how to do this.

Answer (score 1):

In routes.rb:

Without the namespace:

```
constraints subdomain: 'vip' do
  get '/pricing', to: 'somecontroller#someaction', :as=>:vip_pricing
end
```

rake routes:

> vip_pricing GET /pricing(.:format) somecontroller#someaction
>   {:subdomain=>"vip"}

If you keep the namespace:

```
namespace :vip do
  constraints subdomain: 'vip' do
    get 'pricing', to: 'somecontroller#someaction'
    ...
  end
end
```

rake routes:

> vip_pricing GET /vip/pricing(.:format) vip/somecontroller#someaction {:subdomain=>"vip"}

Comment: But As I understand, constraints, will make the route available only when I'm browsing this subdomain. Correct ?

Comment: For the example outside the namespace: if this route "/pricing" is hit within this subdomain "vip", it will route to the controller/action that you specify. That IS what you want, right? In addition, when you use the helper "vip_pricing_url", you will get the subdomain with it as your question asked.